# Is there a way to specify that every \frametitle should have <presentation> as the overlay spec?

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I produce a `beamerarticle`-powered lecture notes from the same file as my presentation.  I do not want to have *any* `\frametitle`s in the lecture notes.  Is there a way to tell Beamer that I want every `\frametitle` to be visible only in `<presentation>` mode?  (Of course, I could define a macro `\presframetitle#1` to be a shorthand for `\frametitle<presentation>{#1}`, but I'd prefer not to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `beamerarticle.sty` defines the frametitle as

```
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{frametitle}{default}{\paragraph*{\insertframetitle}\ \par\noindent\emph{\insertframesubtitle}\par}
```

But you can provide you own definition, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{frametitle}{empty}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this is more or less equivalent to @JosephWright's answer, it has an additional benefit of teaching me about `\defbeamertemplate`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are probably best providing an alternative definition

```
\mode<article>{\renewcommand\frametitle[1]{}}
```

---

Worth noting here is that whilst `beamer` has a global default overlay spec, there is not one for each element. For something like `frametitle` is would be workable, but not for other elements: imagine an `itemize`, which might be in a block, in a column, in both, ...

Comment: You mean `\mode<article>{...}`? But anyway, this is a great idea that didn't cross my mind. If nothing better pops up (and I doubt it will), I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @mbork Yes: was forgetting to flip' the mode!